# I can't get 'grunt watch' to enable 'livereload'

Tags: gruntjs, livereload

I am woking on a *jekyll* project and in the process of building my grunt file, I have been able to get the scripts to concat and minify, buy I am having problems with refreshing my browser...

This is my grunt file.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
        my_target: {
            files: {
                '_site/assets/js/miniFlapJacks.js': ['assets/js/*.js', 'assets/js/plugins/*.js', 'assets/js/vendor/*.js']
            } //files
        } //my_target
    }, //uglify
    watch: {
        options: { livereload: true},
        scripts: {
            files: ['assets/js/*.js', 'assets/js/plugins/*.js', 'assets/js/vendor/*.js'],
            tasks: ['uglify']
        }, // scripts
        html: {
            files:[  '_includes/*.html',
            '_layouts/*.html',
            '_config.yml',
            'index.html']
        }
    } //watch
}) //initConfig
grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch');
} //exports
```

This is my package.json file.

```
 {
      "name": "aortizRefresh",
      "author": "antonio ortiz <17antonio.ortiz@gmail.com>",
      "version" : "0.0.3",
      "homepage": "http://mmistakes.github.io/so-simple-theme/",
      "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme.git"
    },
      "bugs": {
      "url": "https://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme/issues"
    },
      "engines": {
      "node": ">= 0.10.0"
    },
     "dependencies": {
     "grunt": "~0.4.1",
     "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
     "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
     "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.2",
     "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.7.2",
     "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
     "grunt-recess": "~0.3.5",
     "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.2.0",
     "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0"
    }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I found the answer via [1]: http://kctang.github.io/jekyll/livereload/2014/01/25/github-pages-with-jekyll-and-livereload.html/

Comment: What is the URL you're using to view the site? Do you have the livereload script tag inserted into your page? Or are you using the chrome live reload extension? What are you seeing when editing a file?

Comment: Since I am using **jekyll,** my server is `localhost:4000` 
I am using the extension but I am also injecting this before the closing body tag, `<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>`
As for what I see; When I make an edit to the .html file I see the browser reload, but no change to the content...
I am thinking maybe it's cause of **jekyll**?

Comment: Hmm good call. If you make a change and manually refresh the page, does jekyll serve the latest content?

Comment: Just checked, no it doesn't!

Comment: Please look underneath my question, found a link which worked perfectly!